# vw --loss_function logistic --oaa 5 -i model -t -d test.vw -r raw_predictions.txt .. results in empty raw_predictions.txt file

Tags: vowpalwabbit

```
vw --loss_function logistic -i model -t -d test.vw -r raw_predictions.txt 
only testing
raw predictions = raw_predictions.txt
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = test.vw
num sources = 1
average since example example current current current
loss last counter weight label predict features
```

this is the result when I run the above command and it produces an empty file. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Does `test.vw` contain some examples? You can also try `--probabilities -p probs.txt`.

Comment: how to use it? can you give the whole command..

Comment: @MartinPopel vw --loss_function logistic -i model -t dataset\\test.vw --probabilities -p dataset\\probs.txt
used this also but same result.